# AFNetworking, NSURLSession and json Response (Ronak Sankhala)

Tags: json, xcode, web-services, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am trying to get json response from a web-service api. I want to extract product data from the json. I also want to implement this using AFNetworking and i also trying to get response using NSURLSession and its completely working.

```
viewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblTableView;

- (IBAction)btnClickedPostData:(id)sender;



@end

viewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "ResponseTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
NSMutableDictionary *dictArray;
NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tblTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResponseTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ResponseTableViewCell"];
[self connectionString];
}

-(void)connectionString
{
//NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession]; // its working


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);

    dataArray = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"objEventcategoryList"];

    self.tblTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tblTableView.delegate = self;

    [self.tblTableView reloadData];


    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", dataArray);

}];

[dataTask resume];

//    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager]; // its working
//    [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
//        
//        NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse = (NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject;

//        dataArray = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"objEventcategoryList"];
//        
//        self.tblTableView.dataSource = self;
//        self.tblTableView.delegate = self;
//        
//        [self.tblTableView reloadData];
//        
//        NSLog(@"TableView: %@", _tblTableView);
//        
//        
//        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", dataArray);
//    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
//        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
//    }];
}

#pragma marrk
#pragma marrk - TableView DataSource and Deleget
#pragma marrk


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [dataArray count];// its not working
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ResponseTableViewCell *cell = (ResponseTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ResponseTableViewCell"];

dictArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.lblCatID.text = [dictArray objrct:@""];
cell.lblCatID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictArray valueForKey:@"EventCategoryId"]];
cell.lblEventName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictArray valueForKey:@"EventCategoryName"]];
cell.lblCreateDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictArray valueForKey:@"CreatedDate"]];

cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
{
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
{
    [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)])
{
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 144.0;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnClickedPostData:(id)sender {

NSString *tokenString = @"65d188d3f0ab52487001c331584ac819";

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

[defaultConfigObject setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"token" : tokenString}];

NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"];
NSString *paramString = @"lang=en&title=&start=&end=";
NSData *httpBody = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[httpBody length]];

[urlRequest addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//[urlRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:paramString];
[urlRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:@{ @"token" : tokenString}];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:httpBody];
//[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse* respHttp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

    if (!error && respHttp.statusCode == 200) {
         NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
        NSMutableArray *arrArray = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"newslist"];

         NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrArray valueForKey:@"title"]];

        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Details" message:title delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

        [alert show];

        NSLog(@"%@", arrArray);
    }else{

        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

}];
[dataTask resume];

}
@end

//CustomeTableviewCell With XIB
**ResponseTableViewCell.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResponseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCatID;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblEventName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCreateDate;

@end

**ResponseTableViewCell.m**
#import "ResponseTableViewCell.h"

@implementation ResponseTableViewCell
@synthesize lblCatID,lblEventName,lblCreateDate;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
// Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end

// and also download and check JSON demo : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0rS2ZVDMVRiSmJJb1BuQklJSzA[Click to show JSON demo Hear][1]

//add custom table view cell with custom table cell and add label to display information. i used pod to setup AFNetworking.
```

and also download and check JSON demo : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0rS2ZVDMVRiSmJJb1BuQklJSzA[Click to show JSON demo Hear](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0rS2ZVDMVRiSmJJb1BuQklJSzA)

Can anyone suggest a way to do this.me how the things will be done.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0rS2ZVDMVRiUm9IVlFlTndGRDA

Answer (score 0):

[You Can use also use sqlite for the data.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xr1trgy96dzyajm/SqliteDemo.zip?dl=0)